# Makecopy of file in Drive – FolderID error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Line 31 returns the following error

> Cannot find method makeCopy(string,string). (línea 31, archivo
>   "macros")Ignorar

I'm entering the folderID where I want the copy to be stored. 
If i leave it empty, the function makes a copy of the file where the template is stored. Instead of that I want to create it in the destination folder. How could it be fixed? thnx!!

```
function duplicateTemplateQuality(){

/***
  Copia la plantilla de Calidad a la carpeta actual / Copy template to current folder
***/

// Current sheet
  var ssName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  var ssDriveName = DriveApp.getFilesByName(ssName).next();
  var ssDriveId = ssDriveName.getId();


// Customer name extract from current file name
  var findStringCustomer = ssName.indexOf(" - ") +3
  var customer = ssName.slice(findStringCustomer)


// Parent folder current sheet
  var ssParentFolderName = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(customer).next();
  var ssParentFolderID = ssParentFolderName.getId();
  var ssParentFolderURL = ssParentFolderName.getUrl();


// Template to be copied
  var template = "Plantilla Calidad Maestra"   // –> introducir el nombre de la plantilla que se quiera copiar / enter name of template to be copied
  var srcName = DriveApp.getFilesByName(template).next()
  var srcID = srcName.getId()


// Duplicate template 
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(srcID).makeCopy(template + " - " + customer, ssParentFolderID);

}
```

Comment: send it the folder ssParentFolderName  not the id.

Comment: @DaImTo !! It worked!!!  thanks a lot ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[makecopydestination](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination)  takes one paramater

> destination    Folder  the directory to copy the file into.

Which is a [folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) object you appear to be sending it a string.  try using your ssParentFolderName  variable.